# Unable to print user input after executing the script by opening the gnome-terminal

Tags: bash, readline, gnome-terminal

I am trying to make the script which executes on terminal on double click and should ask for user input. To execute script open the gnome-terminal which will execute further script. After taking user input in RESP it unable to print the value passed(y/n). Gnome-terminal with nautilus.

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "read -p 'Include log?(y/n)' RESP
echo '$RESP'
    if[ '$RESP' = 'y' ]; then
       //logic for yes
    else
       //logic for no
    fi; 
exec bash"
```

`echo $RESP` not printing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```sh
bash -c "read -p 'Include log?(y/n)' RESP
echo \$RESP
if [ \$RESP = 'y' ]; then
  echo y
else
  echo n
fi"
```

You need to escape the $ for your variables instead of putting it into '

Comment: So please accept it as an answer. You're helping the community and me by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The `"` in script string made variable empty (not defined variable expands to nothing) . It makes echo empty. I exchanged `"` with `'` and it works fine.

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'read -p "Include log?(y/n)" RESP
                                     echo "$RESP"; sleep 10
                                         if[ "$RESP" = "y" ]; then
                                            echo YES
                                         else
                                            echo NO
                                         fi; 
                                     exec bash'
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! clarify now about ' and "

Comment: NP (No Problem). Been there, did that. You can up vote both of the answers.

Comment: well not have that much of reputation to up vote, when reach i will